# Getting Data and Time during offline using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time, offline

My UI application deployed in Pi and placed in an area where internet connection is not present. I used  default function startTime to display network date and time which need internet connection. I want to display the current time and date without internet connection (offline) is there any solution available? Please help.

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();

    var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = today.getDate();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    if (month < 10) { month = '0' + month; }
    if (day < 10) { day = '0' + day; }
    var dateday = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('timediv').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    document.getElementById('datediv').innerHTML = dateday;

    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}


function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. The javascript `Date()`  just gives the date of the client browser, not anything from network. It does not need internet.

Comment: @Pac0 it is not website it is an JavaScript based User Interface Application deployed inside a raspberry pi with small HMI display. It needs internet connection to display date and time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here, it looks like you're not actually doing any initial call to startTime().  I threw what you had into an HTML file, turned on Airplane Mode on my laptop, refreshed the file locally in a browser and everything worked fine.

Try adding startTime() to the end of your js file, and you should be good to go.

Comment: what if my laptop was in airplane mode for 2 days, whether my time will get updated if i shutdown and open my laptop tomorrow?. what date it will show today's or tomorrow's date?

Comment: i done the initial call in my HTML file like <body onload="startTime()">